# Nginx Third Party Module subs_filter installed but not working returning unknown directive

Tags: nginx

I've installed Nginx previously and recompiled again in order to add two new modules using the usual
./configure and make process.

Nginx is running fine but when I call sub_filter in the .conf file I get an error

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "sub_filter" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-available/nobo.conf:46
```

The version and compile info tells me the module is there (third party module) Do I need to enable it somewhere or have I missed a step in the process

```
nginx version: nginx/1.5.7
built by clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --add-module=rob_nginx_modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module/ --with-http_ssl_module
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: It might be useful for some people to show your `.conf` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says that the unknown directive is "sub_filter", but the module in your configure arguments is the third party nginx_substitutions_filter.

The correct directive for this is subs_filter, with an 's'.

Comment: Awesome Thanks a million, you know your stuff. Want a Job?